# Having trouble with UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to make a report system and need to update some values but it seems to give me this error every time I try and do something, I am using mysql and php:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\functions\offtopic.php on line 22

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_GET['report']))
{
    $query = "UPDATE `offtopicposts` SET `reported`='1', `reported_by`=$_SESSION['user_id'] WHERE `post_id` = $_GET['report']";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['user_id']` set? You are very vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)!

Comment: I am checking if $_GET['report'] is set and the page would redirect them if the that session var is not set

Comment: are you sure this is line 22?  sounds like you might be missing a semi-colon on whatever precedes this line 22...

Comment: I took it out of a file, "$query = "UPDATE `offtopicposts` SET `reported`='1', `reported_by`=$_SESSION['user_id'] WHERE `post_id` = $_GET['report']";" is line 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `offtopicposts` SET `reported`='1', `reported_by`={$_SESSION['user_id']} WHERE `post_id` = {$_GET['report']}";
```

The curly braces might do the trick.

Alternatively, you can concat the string like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `offtopicposts` SET `reported`='1', `reported_by`=" . 
         $_SESSION['user_id'] . " WHERE `post_id` = " .
         (int)$_GET['report'];
```

That also allows you to sneak in the int cast, which is a dirty but effective way to make this script better protected against SQL injection. Even better would be to drop the deprecated `mysql` functions completely, switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`, and use prepared statements.

Comment: Cant accept for another 5 mins... and not enough reputation to up-vote... :-/

Answer (score 0):

you could do this;

```
$query = "UPDATE `offtopicposts` SET `reported`='1', `reported_by`=".$_SESSION['user_id']." WHERE `post_id` = ".$_GET['report'];
```

Or this

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$report = $_GET['report'];
$query = "UPDATE `offtopicposts` SET `reported`='1', `reported_by`=$user_id WHERE `post_id` = $report";
```